# КАК сделать так чтобы запись удалялась автоматически по истечении срока из БазыДанных?

Tags: php, база-данных

Юзер делает заявку и заодно  регистрируется, но  он должен сделать подтверждение по почте,  заявка добавляется в базу как ожидающий подтв. если юзер не сделал подтв. то заявка должна  автоматически удалиться через день. (сайт  я пишу на PHP без фреймворков)

Comment: Где-то на хабре есть статья по поводу видов храния учёток. Способов много.

Comment: Заявка хранится в СУБД верно? Поставьте признак - дату "вышел срок годности", если дата есть и наступила - удаляйте.

Comment: Какая БД используется? Может в ней есть механизм TTL. Тогда достаточно будет выставлять на 1 день его, а после подверждения ставить 0(вечно, к примеру)

Comment: используется MySQL, но  похоже там TTL

Answer (score 4):

**Не нужно удалять заявку**, вы просто формируете заявку и указываете дату до которой она активна, при клик на ссылку, сначала идет проверка даты и если время не истекло учетка активируется и лишь тогда ссылка удаляется, иначе выводится сообщение о том, что ссылка устарела и предложение сформировать новую ссылку, когда пользователь формирует новую ссылку, вот тогда вы обновляете ее новой как и дату.

Comment: Если вы собираетесь сделать событие типа удалять по времени, это нужно настраивать крон или подобные механизмы, которые будут отслеживать, а это лишнее когда всё на много проще делается!

Comment: вот вот,  я хочу заявку удалить  по  истечении  времени,  так как никто не увидит и не кликнет по нему(если я правильно понял ваш ответ), и еще почитал про кроны и  демоны,  но как именно реализовать не понял(был б благодарен если вы кинули какие то ссылки а то мне кажется я даже не правильно ищу:) )

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы как раз не прибегать к механизму крона, зачем грузить без толку сервер лишними задачами и тратить на это ресурсы, а ссылку чистить и не надо, пусть она себе висит, точней там должен храниться хеш, пока к нему не обратиться, а если этого никогда не произдейте, значит ничего страшно не будет, такой способ реализации используется везде, а то, что вы хотите сделать через крон это лишняя и бессмысленная нагрузка на сервер!!!

Comment: Вы просто генерити некий хешь и записываете его в поле пользователя в базу, к примеру: `OVsZ4DNa` а путь уже будет вида: `http://temp.ru/activate?user_id=11&hash=OVsZ4DNa`

Comment: но  я же уже добавил  в базу целую  заявку с несколькими полями и  фотками, она просто  ожидает  активаций, ее же над удалить как то, если  не активируется